# oozie intial instance and start time giving error on missing dataset

Tags: oozie-coordinator, oozie-workflow

I am new to oozie and trying to understand dataset.xml. I have following dataset and trying to understand what exactly oozie is trying to validate here. what is the meaning of initial instance and what uri-template is doing here(not clear on oozie document)

```
<dataset name="sample" frequency="${coord:hours(1)}" initial-instance="2022-01-10T00:00Z" timezone="UTC">
        <uri-template>${hdfsdir}/filepath/${YEAR}${MONTH}${DAY}${HOUR}</uri-template>
        <done-flag>_SUCCESS</done-flag>
 </dataset>
```

Similarly, in coordinator I have following for input and output dataset. Here what is the significance of current(-5) and start parameter?

```
<coordinator-app name="test" frequency="${freq}" start="2022-01-10T00:00Z" end="2023-04-11T00:00Z" timezone="UTC" xmlns="uri:oozie:coordinator:0.4" xmlns:sla="uri:oozie:sla:0.2">
 
  <data-in name="raw" dataset="raw_data">
            <instance>${coord:current(-5)}</instance>
   </data-in>

<data-out name="processed" dataset="raw_out">
                <instance>${coord:current(-5)}</instance>
       </data-out>
```

Can someone explain what oozie is expecting on the datasets?

Thanks, bab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without looking at the documentation, here's what I can guess.

- `initial-instance` - When is the `dataset` *first* available? If you try to provide a timestamp before this in a workflow or coordinator, you can expect an error.
- After which, a positive `frequency` will "count up" from that timestamp
- `uri-template` uses built-in Oozie variables to determine what pattern those files exist in the filesystem.

`coord:current(-5)` will multiply 5 by the dataset `frequency`, and return the 5th **previous** instance... Giving you a dataset 5 hours before the time that the coordinator was started.

So, for your example, you have `dataset name="sample"` defined, but your `data-in` and `data-out` tags do not reference this, so I don't think anything will run...

Here's the docs for `coord:current` (might say something different from my answer) https://oozie.apache.org/docs/5.2.1/CoordinatorFunctionalSpec.html#a6.6.1._coord:currentint_n_EL_Function_for_Synchronous_Datasets

Section 5.1 seems to mostly answer your question